# Why does my USB 2.0 Harddrive unmount after I think one Day

Tags: linux, usb, hard-disk, arm

Hello I want to know why my USB 2.0 2.5" Harddrive unmounts After I think one day. It has a Y USB Cable and is connected to a Odroid C2 running Diet Pi. One Cable is connected to the USB Port on the Odroid and one to an external Powersource because it didn't work at all with both in the USB Ports.

Does Somebody know why and how to fix it, because there is a Minecraft Server running on and it's chrashing when it unmounts (or whatever it does)?

Edit: It isn't unmounting but there are no more files shown there. And nothing can write to it. Is there something I can post that someone can Investigate this further?

Comment: First check if it is actually umounting. If it is, it will leave some trace in the logs. You could try `sudo dmesg` to check that. It could be sleeping. In that case you should still be able to do something like `ls` but it will take some seconds to start.

Comment: Quick hack might be a cron job that cats a file on the storage device every few hours to keep it active